# Ambiguity in variables inside callbacks inside constructors

Tags: javascript, class, variables, scope

```js
class A {
    flag = 0;  // flag 1
    constructor(timer) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            flag = 1;  // flag 2
        }, timer);
    }
}
```

What variable is `flag 2` referring to? `flag 1` or a local flag inside `function()`?
How do I unambiguously refer to either of them?

Comment: flag 1 and flag 2 are different variables. `flag` doesn't exist inside the `setTimeout` or the `constructor` so it should throw a reference error.

Comment: `flag = 1`  That's a global variable.

Comment: @Keith I get a reference error when I run the provided code

Comment: @evolutionxbox  Yes, in strict mode it will.   I believe most browsers will force strict mode for a class, but if say transpiled code is used it might not pick it up, and you will get a global var called `flag` with a value of 1..

Answer (score 0):

You need to know about [`context`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) in Javascript.

**[Solution 1: capture `this` keyword]**

```js
class A{
    constructor(timer){
        var that = this; 
        that.flag = 0;
        setTimeout(function(){
            that.flag = 1;
        }, timer);
    }
}

var x = new A(200);
console.log(x.flag); // 
setTimeout(() => console.log(x.flag), 300);
```

**[Solution 2: use `bind` method]**

```js
class A{
        constructor(timer){
            this.flag = 0;
            setTimeout(function(){
                this.flag = 1;
            }.bind(this), timer);
        }
    }

    var x = new A(200);
    console.log(x.flag); // 
    setTimeout(() => console.log(x.flag), 300);
```

**[Solution 3: use [`arrow func`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) of ES6 feature]** ==> Highly recommend to use this.

```js
class A{
        constructor(timer){
            this.flag = 0;
            setTimeout(() => this.flag = 1, timer);
        }
    }
    
var x = new A(200);
console.log(x.flag)
setTimeout(() => console.log(x.flag), 300);
```

Comment: @Yunus Poonawala Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help.